# Issues with ffmpeg and rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg

I'm creating thumbnails from a **webm** file, the problem is that every time the script runs my development server *(webrick)* stops and there is no errors in the output, the images are created but the server just stop.

Answer (score 1):

I changed exec("") for IO.popen("") and that resolved the issue.